# DesktopDatePicker as React Component cannot change the format of date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the format of the component but in the UI is still month-year-date displayed.

```
 <DesktopDatePicker
          inputVariant="outlined"
          label="Pick-up date"
          id="date-picker-dialog"
          name="startDate"
          onChange={(val) => {
            formik.setFieldValue("startDate", val);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          value={formik.values.startDate}
          // format date-month-year
          format="dd-MM-yyyy"
          error={formik.errors.startDate && formik.touched.startDate}
        />
```

Comment: add this to component inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to component `inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"`